# Tooltip in d3 js (Bullet charts)

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);
  var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("class", "bullet")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).on("mouseover", function(d) {        
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div.html("Tooltip" + "<br/>"  + d.measures);    
            })
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(chart);
```

Getting below result:
[image]

Result what I am expecting:
[image]

Is there any error in my code or do I need to do things differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update the position of the tool-tip div on mouse over.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {        
      div.transition()        
         .duration(200)      
         .style("opacity", .9)
         .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")    //Set X  
         .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");  //Set Y
      div.html("Tooltip" + "<br/>"  + d.measures);    
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works. But I need to add (d3.event.pageX - 250) to keep tooltip inside the chart. Is there any way to handle that dynamically.

Comment: The value 250 may be the offset top value of the SVG. You can use `d3.select("svg").node().offsetTop` in that case.

Comment: Still do not work . Please see the [link](http://postimg.org/image/kuhdxi8gv/) for the issue I am facing.

Comment: Okay. It may be related to the position or overflow of the container div. To get the mouse position relative to the hover element, you can use d3.mouse(el). In your code,  `.style("left", d3.mouse(this)[0] + "px") .style("top", d3.mouse(this)[1] + "px");` should work.

Comment: Well the above results this [link](http://postimg.org/image/8l88r2xl3/). The values change but the tool tip do not navigate.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: I have not used fiddle much but have managed to put my code in it. The html section has included bullets.js which I have included in JS section and the data.json data is resolved in the variable called data in the html page. Please see the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xbrufweb/1/).

Comment: Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/QBteA/119/). But I was not able to reproduce the issue in this fiddle. Since you are using margins, in your code, you can try adjusting pageX and pageY value based on that also.

Comment: Thanks! Looks I need to adjust it by +/- hard coded value.

Comment: This post of mine is put onhold. Can you please help me in this regard [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714394/what-is-the-name-of-the-below-graph-chartwant-to-you-in-d3-js).